# Trigger count insert and delete

Tags: mysql, sql-update, trigger, sql-insert, delete

Estou com um problema em uma trigger que tenho aqui, quero que essa trigger após contar e inserir na tabela x, ela delete o valor que ele buscou na tabela y, conseguir fazer ele contar e inserir mas não estou conseguindo fazer ele contar, inserir e depois deletar.

Meu código:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE g5_member 
    set mb_credit = mb_credit + (ROUND(RAND()*10,0)%7) + 10 
    WHERE mb_id = NEW.PlayerID;
    DELETE FROM PlayerID;
END
```

Comment: Em que modo está o trigger a ser montado? Antes ou depois de que acções?

Comment: Publica o código todo . Ocorre algum erro ? A trigger é em qual tabela ?

Comment: Desculpe nao ter respondido antes, o codigo e apenas isso ai mesmo, o codigo inseri os pontos normalmente, mas quero que apos inserir ele delete as informaçoes da outra tabela!